# Xcode 4 - Disable assembly debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging

When I am debugging an iPhone app code, the debugger shows assembly code.

I'd like to see only Objective-C code, not  assembly.

I have deselected the option Product -> Debug Workflow -> Show Disassembly When Debugging but still nothing.

Could you please help me...!

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Is it showing assembly language instead of Objective-C for your code? You will get assembly language in the debugger if you step into code you didn't write, such as the code in Apple's frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It's now clear...!